# Does a polearm's reach stack with the Warden's Thorn Strike's Melee 2?

Tags: dnd-4e, warden

The Warden's Thorn Strike has a range of **Melee 2**, it's keywords are **Primal** and **Weapon**.  A polearm has Reach letting you attack 2 squares away.

Does a polearm's range stack with Warden's Thorn Strike for a range of 3?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No**,

They do not stack unfortunately.  You need one or the other to state that "Your melee reach increases by 1"

Examples would be:

- **Reaching Action**<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=285)</sup>: Class power from the Verdant Lord Paragon Path
- **Staff Expertise**<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=3151)</sup>: feat increases melee reach for staff melee attacks.

Comment: The difference here is between Melee 2 and Melee Weapon.

Answer (score 5):

The Rules Compendium p100 reads, in the **Range** entry:

> **Melee [number]:** The power can be used against a target that is within
>   the specified number of squares of the power's origin square.
>
> **Melee weapon:** The power can be used against a target within the reach
>   of the melee weapon that is used with the power. [snip] If a creature has a reach greater than 1, the creature uses its reach for the
>   power's range, instead of the weapon's reach. If the same creature uses a
>   weapon that has a reach greater than 1, the creature still uses its own reach
>   but adds 1.

So, reach weapons only add to reach when using powers with a range of **Melee weapon**